# How to properly ignore NA when comparing two dates?

Tags: r, date, if-statement, dplyr

I have two date variables

```
ID Date1       Date2      
1  2019-09-10  2019-09-09 
1  2019-12-11  2019-12-01
1  NA          2019-12-08
2  2019-09-11  2019-09-25
2  2019-11-05  2019-11-15
2  2019-12-05  NA
3  2019-09-19  2019-09-11
3  2019-10-22  2019-10-17
```

I want to compare if Date 1 is after Date 2 by running below codes

```
df %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(Result = ifelse(!is.na(Date1) < !is.na(Date2), "Yes", 
"No"))
```

What I want is:

```
ID Date1       Date2       Result
1  2019-09-10  2019-09-09  No
1  2019-12-11  2019-12-01  No
1  NA          2019-12-08  NA
2  2019-09-11  2019-09-25  Yes
2  2019-11-05  2019-11-15  Yes
2  2019-12-05  NA          NA
3  2019-09-19  2019-09-11  No
3  2019-10-22  2019-10-17  No
```

If I run this, I get "Yes" for the ones that contain NA..
I don't want to remove NAs because I still need this missing information later on. I am not sure why !is.na() does not work in this case. Any help would be appreciated!

- I also tried difftime() and same thing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can remove `is.na()` in your `ifelse()` statement, which will keep the missing information

```
df %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(Result = ifelse(Date1 < Date2, "Yes", "No"))
```

Comment: Ah okay i see! Can I ask why it is not the case when I use filter(! Date1 > Date2)? instead of mutating yes/no variable, I'd like to filter the 'no'.  But it drops rows with NA

Comment: @JNB `! Date1 > Date2` could be `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NA`, but the you cannot filter `NA`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two logical vectors with each other, `!is.na(Date1)` and `!is.na(Date2)`. Since `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be coerced to numeric vectors, the inequality compares each value, where `NA` containing cells will evaluate to `TRUE` and hence be "greater" than cells not containing `NA`. You just need to remove the call to `is.na` there, the comparison will maintain `NA` for `Result` in rows wherever `Date1` or `Date2` has a value of `NA`.

Note that you don't need to use `group_by` here since you're operating on each row individually.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Result = ifelse(Date1 < Date2, "Yes", "No"))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>      ID Date1      Date2      Result
#>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <chr> 
#> 1     1 2019-09-10 2019-09-09 No    
#> 2     1 2019-12-11 2019-12-01 No    
#> 3     1 NA         2019-12-08 <NA>  
#> 4     2 2019-09-11 2019-09-25 Yes   
#> 5     2 2019-11-05 2019-11-15 Yes   
#> 6     2 2019-12-05 NA         <NA>  
#> 7     3 2019-09-19 2019-09-11 No    
#> 8     3 2019-10-22 2019-10-17 No
```